# Vertical spacing in diagram

Tags: math-mode, tikzmark

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \[
        \tikzmarknode{base}{2}^{\tikzmarknode{exp}{3}}=2\cdot 2\cdot 2
    \]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[stealth-,OrangeRed] (base)-- ($ (base.south west) + (-2ex,0) $) node[inner sep=1pt,left,font=\footnotesize\sffamily,OrangeRed] {base};
        \draw[stealth-,Cerulean] (exp) -- ($ (base.north east) + (2ex,2ex) $) node[inner sep=0pt, above right,font=\footnotesize\sffamily,Cerulean] {exponent};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I ensure proper spacing above and below the diagram? That is, I would like the overly to respect the math spacing above and below and not bleed out into the text above.

Also if there are possible or better ways of labeling the diagram I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

Measure the distances and add them.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \[
        \tikzmarknode{base}{2}^{\tikzmarknode{exp}{3}}=2\cdot 2\cdot 2
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline={(aux.base)}]
      \begin{scope}[overlay]
        \draw[stealth-,OrangeRed] (base)-- ($ (base.south west) + (-2ex,0) $)
         node[inner sep=1pt,left,font=\footnotesize\sffamily,OrangeRed] (aux1){base};
        \draw[stealth-,Cerulean] (exp) -- ($ (base.north east) + (2ex,2ex) $) 
        node[inner sep=0pt, above right,font=\footnotesize\sffamily,Cerulean] 
        (aux2){exponent};
      \end{scope}       
      \path node(aux){\vphantom{.}}
        let \p1=($(aux1.north)-(aux.base)$),
            \p2=($(aux1.south)-(aux.base)$),
            \p3=($(aux2.north)-(aux.base)$),
            \p4=($(aux2.south)-(aux.base)$) in 
            foreach \z in {1,...,4} {(0,\y\z)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can also use `fit` to shorten the code a bit. (This even rhymes.;-)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,fit}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \[
        \tikzmarknode{base}{2}^{\tikzmarknode{exp}{3}}=2\cdot 2\cdot 2
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline={(aux.base)}]
      \begin{scope}[overlay]
        \draw[stealth-,OrangeRed] (base)-- ($ (base.south west) + (-2ex,0) $)
         node[inner sep=1pt,left,font=\footnotesize\sffamily,OrangeRed] (aux1){base};
        \draw[stealth-,Cerulean] (exp) -- ($ (base.north east) + (2ex,2ex) $) 
        node[inner sep=0pt, above right,font=\footnotesize\sffamily,Cerulean] 
        (aux2){exponent};
        \node[fit=(aux1)(aux2),inner sep=0pt](auxf){};
      \end{scope}       
      \path node(aux){\vphantom{.}}
        let \p1=($(auxf.north)-(aux.base)$),
            \p2=($(auxf.south)-(aux.base)$) in 
            (0,\y1) (0,\y2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain which part calculates the height?

Comment: @azetina Sure. Maybe the second code is easier to understand. We fit the two nodes carrying the annotations in `auxf`. We also place a dummy node `aux` to know where the baseline is. Then  `let \p1=($(auxf.north)-(aux.base)$),
            \p2=($(auxf.south)-(aux.base)$) in`  will lead to `\y1` being the vertical distance from the baseline of our dummy node upwards, i.e. to the topmost point of `auxf`, its north anchor,  and the `\y2` the vertical distance downwards.